# Knockout Javascript select returns Object object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout with a select like so:

```
   function journal(data) {
        this.id = ko.observable(data.ID);
        this.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
   }

   var self = this;
   self.journals = ko.observableArray([]);

   $.getJSON("/JournalEntries/GetJournalsList", function (data) {
            var mappedJournals = $.map(data, function (item) { return new journal(item) });
            self.journals(mappedJournals);
   });

   self.getData = function(journalid) {
        alert(journalid);
   };
```

And in HTML part is:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.journals, optionsCaption: 'Choose...', value: 'id', optionsText: 'name', event:{ change: $root.getData }"></select>
```

And it doesn't come back with an ID, just '[Object object]'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Open the developer tools and log it to the console instead of alerting. What does the object contain? Also, if that doesn't prove eventful, try to create a new observable, like `var test = ko.observable();` and use that as your `value`.. like `value: test,`.. and alert it and see what you get... Like example 3 in the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't want to react to events this way in knockout.

If you want to react to a change in the selected value in a `<select>`, save the selected value to an observable (via the `value` binding) and subscribe to that observable (or base computed values on that observable).

```js
function Journal(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.ID);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // data
    self.journals = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedJournal = ko.observable();

    // subscriptions
    self.selectedJournal.subscribe(function (journal) {
       if (journal) alert( journal.id() );
    });

    // init
    var newJournals = ko.utils.arrayMap([
        {ID: 1, Name: "Item 1"},
        {ID: 2, Name: "Item 2"},
        {ID: 3, Name: "Item 3"},
        {ID: 4, Name: "Item 4"},
    ], function(item) { return new Journal(item); });

    self.journals(newJournals);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="
  options: journals,
  optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
  optionsText: 'name',
  value: selectedJournal
"></select>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways - your way here and the way that I posted. I wanted to do it this way, but it wasn't working either so I was trying it the other way. The answer actually lies within your answer... what I have found is I needed to put this: "journal.id()" instead of "journal" or "journal.id" - the end parenthesis make all the difference. It also works with "ko.unwrap(journal.id)".

Comment: This is the way I use it and it has worked very well for me. Never have had an issue.

Comment: @Barray Using `ko.unwrap()` is actually smarter because it makes no assumptions about the nature of the value.

Answer (score 1):

self.journals is an Observable array, just like a normal array in javascript you need to push, the item into the array

```
 self.journals.push(mappedJournals);
```

Comment: with this I don't even get any options, without push I do get options

Comment: value = selected value, optionsValue: 'id'

Comment: I don't have any problems seeing the options... just when I try get the value on select change... the alert reads: "[object Object]"

Comment: you need to go deeper into the obj, perhaps post your json or a fiddle, thx @SHammelburg

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html shows the select element binding options